# Applying for ACS skills assessment and student visa

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, australia, student-visa

I have applied to few colleges in Australia for my masters degree and I am expecting to study there starting from August. For this to happen I will also be applying for a student visa in a couple of months. My plan is to apply for Australian PR once I start my course so that I don't have any problem in finding a job once I graduate.

I already meet the 65 point requirement for Australian PR. But I am not starting the PR process right away because I was told that having an active pr application while applying for a student visa can indicate dual intent and can lead to the rejection of the student visa. Is this correct?

Can I start the PR process once I start studying in Australia? Well this void my student visa?

Also please let me know if I can get my skill assessment done from Australian computer society before I apply for student visa and submit the expression of interest after I enter Australia with the student visa?  Or should I start the skill assessment also only after entering Australia with a student visa?

Please guide me in this regard.

Comment: Please see the [help] and try to narrow your posts to one question per post. It's a lot more likely to be answered.